# Mahattan Function For This Puzzle Game

Tags: algorithm

I'm finding an optimize solution for this kind of game :

give a board game with size : 3 x 5. in this board game. there are 14 pieces and one empty slot (as 15 puzzle game), that all pieces around empty slot can move to this. Each piece will be assign with one color (can be duplicate on many pieces).

Game will be end when last row is identical with first row.

For example :

an initial state is :

```
     | red   | red    | red | red
red  | blue  | white  | blue| blue
white| yellow| blue   | red | yellow
```

There are many ways to end goal. this is one way, that need 23 moves :

```
red | white | yellow | red | blue
red | blue  | red    | blue|
red | white | yellow | red | blue
```

There is other, just need 16 moves :

```
red   | blue  | red   | red | blue
yellow| white | white |     | yellow
red   | blue  | red   | red | blue
```

So, I need to find how to use minimum move to achieve end goal.

I try (and think) to use Mahattan distance for this problem. But I don't know, how to define   an Mahattan function for this problem. Any idea for this ?

Thanks :)

Comment: To be honest, I don't think manhattan distance has a lot to do with this. Maybe you can use breadth-first  search

Comment: @NiklasB. can you tell me more, please. because I need a cost function to determine "how good this state is". When I try to solve `15 puzzle game`, I use `Mahattan distance` to find distance from current state to end state (that we can know). So, I think I can solve this puzzle by define `Mahattan distance` too. How can I use BFS to find cost function ? thanks :)

Comment: What you're looking for is called an *admissible heuristic*.  Here a simple one is: Count the number of columns in which the tile in the top row disagrees with the tile in the bottom row.  This is a valid lower bound on the number of moves since at least one of the two rows will need to have its tile in that column changed before the puzzle can be solved, and this change will take at least one move.

Comment: @j_random_hacker yes, i'm currently using that function for my algorithm. define above function as A. a state X value will be : `A() + moveToGetThere()` But I think it will make algorithm "slowly" go to optimize state. (because a row just has 5 pieces, so values only range from 0 -> 5, too small) So, I think there is another better function :)

Comment: @Annoymous: If you have already got something and need to improve it, then *please tell people that at the start so that they don't waste time doing work you have already done.*

Comment: @j_random_hacker i'm sorry. because when i ask this question, i just thinking about mahattan function, how to define it. that's why I forget to say all my work have done here. I'm sorry

Comment: No worries, just something to think about for next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we have this `current state`:

```
     | white
red  | blue
```

And this `goal state`:

```
white | red
blue  |
```

Then we have the following heuristic:

```
h = SUM { Manhattan_Distance(x) | x is a unique cell }
```

In here, we have for example:

```
xxxx | white
xxxx | xxxx

white | xxxx
xxxx  | xxxx
```

So `Manhattan_Distance(white) = 1`

```
xxxx | xxxx
red  | xxxx

xxxx | red
xxxx | xxxx
```

And `Manhattan_Distance(red) = 2`

```
xxxx | xxxx
xxxx | blue

xxxx | xxxx
blue | xxxx
```

And `Manhattan_Distance(blue) = 1`

So, `h = SUM { 1, 2, 1 } = 3`

---

Adjacent state is a state that we can obtain by making 1 legal move.

We can make a linear search using `g = min(h)`

Or a BFS with `g(x) = h(x) + depth(x)`

Answer (score 1):

In each column there is a pair of tiles that need to have the same colour. A heuristic for estimating the number of moves to make the pair a specific colour, say red, is the Manhattan distance from the top tile to the nearest red tile plus the Manhattan distance from the bottom tile to the nearest red tile.

```
     | red   | RED  * | red | red
red  | blue  | white  | blue| blue
white| yellow| blue * | RED | yellow
```

*For the pair of tiles in the third column (marked with an `*`), the closest red tiles (uppercased) have distances 0 and 1, so the estimate is 0 + 1 = 1.*

The same can be done for the other colours. The final estimate for the pair is the minimum over all the colours, since any colour will do.

*For the third column in the board above, the other estimates are 1 + 1 = 2 for white, 2 + 1 = 3 for yellow, and 2 + 0 = 2 for blue. The minimum is 1.*

The total estimate for the entire board is the sum of the estimates for all the pairs.

---

This is a pretty crude heuristic. For one thing, it doesn't take into account the fact that two distinct tiles of the same colour are required.

One possible improvement is to do a two-source breadth first search from the pair to find the nearest two tiles of a specific colour. The search can be converted into a simple loop, and all the colours can be searched simultaneously.